# I need the version of my assembly but I got the version of the engine who run the tests

Tags: c#, version, teamcity, .net-assembly

I am using teamcity for my night builds and test runnings.

My code is written in c# with visual studio 2010 professional

I need the version of my assembly but I got the version of the engine who run the tests

Here is my actual code :
`String AssemblyVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can, using reflection, get the assembly which is currently executing...

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

or the assembly that called the methoid which is executing ....

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
```

or the entry point assembly (the one that started this process).

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
```

otherwise, to get any arbitrary loaded assembly, you need to specify the type of some defined `Type` (`class` or `struct`) that is defined in that assembly...

```
Assembly.GetAsembly(Type myType);
```

Which assembly do you want the version for??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`, just check the assembly of some type in your assembly:

```
var assemblyVersion = typeof(MyType).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Comment: @JTomas MyType is some type defined in the assembly whose version you want (i. e. the assembly you're testing)

Answer (score 0):

It means take any defined class in your assembly.

ex u have an Employee class defined in your assembly then u can use it as

```
var assemblyVersion = typeof(Employee).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()
```